# BR tag has no effect when parent has height

Tags: html, css

This question is being asked out of cursosity. I've just noticed when I have this bit of markup:

```
<div style="height: 20px; background-color: yellow;">
    Test
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

The `br` tags have no effect. However, if the parent has no height i.e. `height: auto` - the `br` tags become effective - why is this the case?

Is this the same in all cases i.e. across different doc types and browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `<br>` tags *do* have an effect. If I change your markup as follows:

```
<div style="overflow: visible; height: 20px; background-color: yellow;">
    Test
    <br />
    Test 2
    <br />
    Test 3
    <br />
    Test 4
</div>
```

Then I can see the effect -- [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/Y45VF/1/).

[image: Lines of text overflowing a div]

The default overflow is `visible` (in my browser, anyway), so the text visibly overflows the `<div>`. In the case of `<br>`, you're just getting empty lines extending below the `<div>`, which are invisible, but present.

If you add `overflow: scroll` to the `<div>`, you can also see the effect -- there are clearly blank lines at the end of your text, that you can scroll through. Markup:

```
<div style="overflow: scroll; height: 20px; background-color: yellow;">
    Test
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/Y45VF/)).

So, the `<br>`s do make a difference, but with the height set on the `<div>` you don't actually get to see the difference if there are *only* `<br>`s, as they are, by definition, just line breaks, and not directly visible.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you think about it then this should be the case on all elements/text in that div... When content is to big then you will get a scroll if you add "overflow:hidden;"

But why would you set a height on an element that might need to grow taller?

Comment: In that example, if I put `overflow:hidden;` it doesn't show scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide an `overflow: auto` to your div, you'll be able to see that the `<BR>`s are indeed there.

Comment: If the parent has height, it won't make a difference.

Comment: It does make a difference for me when I add `overflow: scroll` http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/Y45VF/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the same across all browsers.

## overflow and auto

Your text is too high for the content box. So if overflows.
As you haven't set an overflow style, it gets the default which is `visible`, according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow).

See an explanatory example: http://jsfiddle.net/bsZG7/
(The second div has padding-left for the convenience of understanding what is going on.)

Because the content that spills is not visible, you do not notice it.

## misusing `br`

The br element represents a line break.
And, quoting
http://developers.whatwg.org/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element :

> While line breaks are usually represented in visual media by physically moving subsequent text to a new line, a style sheet or user agent would be equally justified in causing line breaks to be rendered in a different manner, for instance as green dots, or as extra spacing.

You should not be using it to style, as you seem to be.
If you want a margin on the bottom of some box, give it a class or id and put in your css file `margin-bottom: 30px;`.

## inline styles

You should avoid inline styles as much as possible, instead placing all styles inside a css file. You might just be doing it for the sake of testing, but I will leave the suggestion anyway.

There are many justifications for this, including that the css file can be cached, that you centralize styles in a styles file, that you avoid repetition, that you simplify changes... the list goes on and on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<body>
<div style="height: 20px; background-color: yellow;">
    Test
    <br />
    Line2
    <br />
    Line3
    <br />
    Line4
    </div>
</body>
```