# When are <br> elements ignored when within a paragraph?

Tags: html, line-breaks, specifications

I have found out that sometimes, `<br>` elements are not rendered in the browsers I use (Firefox and Chrome).

```
<p>Hello<br></p>
<p>Hello<br></p>
```

will be rendered the same as :

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
```

In the same way,

```
<p>Hello <a href="https://ddg.gg">ddg<br></a></p>
<p>Hello</p>
```

and :

```
<p>Hello <a href="https://ddg.gg">ddg</a></p>
<p>Hello</p>
```

will also be rendered without any linebreaks when opened in the browser.

I couldn't find the section in the HTML spec that specifies this behavior, do you know where to find the spec for this or could you phrase this behavior in a simple way ?

I would also be interested in reasons for having this behavior if you know them.

**EDIT** : I know it is quite "incorrect" to place br elements at this position in the HTML, I'm not the one who generates this HTML, but I need to convert this HTML to another format so I'm interested in understanding how browsers handle this case.

Comment: As this concerns rendering, I'd say the CSS spec is the place to look in rather than HTML. Let me have a look. I do know that <br> is... kinda weird in terms of CSS, and different browsers actually implement it differently internally, which further complicates things.

Comment: The element is not supposed to be used as you do in your sample. It will break a line text, but you don't have any text after the br. https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-br-element

Comment: What do you **expect** of this? Closing a paragraph will already provide space

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, I'm creating a converter from HTML to another format, and I know that `<br>` is not supposed to be used like this. I'm not the person creating this HTML, someone else has, and I want to still properly handle it. I want to replicate the browser's behavior in this case, and even if it is wrongly used, knowing a bit more about how this will be rendered is important to me.

Comment: OK, the implementation of <br> *described* in terms of CSS (but not guaranteed to be implemented as such) is simple enough: it functions like a line feed (&#x0A;) with white-space: pre. I don't know whether to look in the CSS spec or some other spec (Unicode?) for where it says that a forced line break at the end of a line does not need to be rendered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my opinion most browsers follow the **[WHATWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHATWG)** specification and I would do it also. **[World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium)** has On 28 May 2019 **[announced](https://www.w3.org/blog/2019/05/w3c-and-whatwg-to-work-together-to-advance-the-open-web-platform/)** that WHATWG would be the sole publisher of the HTML and DOM standards. If we have in this specification following rules only, then I would follow those rules.

**WHATWG has following recommendations for `br` element:**

> The `br` element represents a line break.
>
> **Note:** *While line breaks are usually represented in visual media by physically moving subsequent text to a new line, a style sheet or
> user agent would be equally justified in causing line breaks to be
> rendered in a different manner, for instance as green dots, or as
> extra spacing.*
>
> `br` elements must be used only for line breaks that are actually part
> of the content, as in poems or addresses.
>
> The following example is correct usage of the `br` element:
>
> ```
> <p>P. Sherman<br>
> 42 Wallaby Way<br>
> Sydney</p>
> ```
>
> `br` elements must not be used for separating thematic groups in a
> paragraph.
>
> The following examples are non-conforming, as they abuse the `br`
> element:
>
> ```
> <p><a ...>34 comments.</a><br>
> <a ...>Add a comment.</a></p>
> <p><label>Name: <input name="name"></label><br>
> <label>Address: <input name="address"></label></p>
> ```
>
> Here are alternatives to the above, which are correct:
>
> ```
> <p><a ...>34 comments.</a></p>
> <p><a ...>Add a comment.</a></p>
> <p><label>Name: <input name="name"></label></p>
> <p><label>Address: <input name="address"></label></p>
> ```
>
> If a paragraph consists of nothing but a single `br` element, it
> represents a placeholder blank line (e.g. as in a template). Such
> blank lines must not be used for presentation purposes.
>
> Any content inside `br` elements must not be considered part of the
> surrounding text.
>
> **Note:** ***[This element has rendering requirements involving the bidirectional algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#bidireq)**.*
>
> ***Source: [WHATWG: The `br` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element)***

In your examples you have `br` elements in `<br></p>` and in `<br></a></p>` on the end of `<p>` element. The new line on the end of this element does nothing, but only in this case. In such of this cases you can ignore it. It is also the same in the case of `br` elements in `<br></a></div>` and in `<br></div>` on the end of `<div>` element.

**Cite from WHATWG recommendations (see above):** *If a paragraph consists of nothing but a single `br` element, it represents a placeholder blank line*. Also it is **not *empty*** (like user *kalkronline* wrote). And in case of W3C and WHATWG opinions conflict user agents have to follow WHATWG recomandations (see above).

Do not forget about style possibility (for ex. `clear`) for `br` element.

---

**Update from 25/06/2020**

I want to post and explain the **cite from WHATWG recommendations again(see above):**

> *If a paragraph consists of nothing but a single `br` element, it represents a placeholder blank line*.

This is showed like:

```css
p{border:1px dashed red}
```

```html
<b>1. example:</b>
<code>&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</code>
<p><br></p>
<b>2. example:</b>
<code>&lt;p&gt;I am a line&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</code>
<p>I am a line<br><br></p>
<b>3. example:</b>
<code>&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</code>
<p></p>
```

The case in first example means that this *represents a placeholder blank line*. And this is **not *empty***! Why? Because a placeholder blank line has some font size properties. In other case it would be like in third example – **empty**.

The case in the second example shows us two `br` elements on the end of block element and we can see that last `br` element was ignored, but the second `br` element from the end has his own line.

The user *kalkronline* **[has done the research again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62582175)**, but he has found wrong explanation wih misinterpretation from user *Rei*. The explanation from user *Rei* is only at the first look logical, but if we read what I wrote than we will see that he has done **[logical mistakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy)**. My second example shows us user's *Rei* mistake because according to his description we would have to have an empty line. The cite from user's *Rei* misinterpretation:

> *Because the line has zero characters, it is rendered as an empty line.*

**But it is because no elements follows after it in this block element!**

### Conclusion

I would like to write some rules for your converter:

1. *If a paragraph consists of nothing but a single `br` element, it represents a placeholder blank line* (from WHATWG recommendations)
2. All `br` elements at the end of block elements if after them is nothing coming should be ignored.
3. Only the last `br` element from two or more `br` elements on the end of block elements has to be ignored. But previous `br` elements have to have an own line with font size height.
4. You have to follow all WHATWG recommendations.

---

**Usefull links:**

- **[WHATWG: The br element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element)**
- **[`<br>`: The Line Break element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) (MDN)**
- **[WHATWG: HTML Living Standard. The definition of '`<p>`' in that specification.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element)**
- **[`<p>`: The Paragraph element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) (MDN)**
- **[Me and others. 1971 USSR](https://youtube.com/watch?v=fuIXiXqv978)** (very good documentary film about logical mistakes and mind manipulations with english subtitles(turn them on))

Comment: I'm not interested in the part about recommendations about how to use `<br>`, I'm only interested in knowing how the browsers understand the case that I put, and when exactly `<br>` has no effect

Comment: @edi9999, in the cite from WHATWG in my answer you can see recommendations for `<br>` element, wich browsers uses for rendering as rules. And it is not "how to use" but how browsers have to handle it in rendering. In your converter you have also to follow some rules. In the part after the cite from WHATWG I wrote the solution for you: *The new line (`<br>`) on the end of this element does nothing, but only in this case. In such of this cases you can ignore it.* Please see my answer again. 

Comment: Here you are generalising from `If a paragraph consists of nothing but a single br element` to : `If a paragraph ends with a br element and has no content after it`, without refering to an official source.

Comment: @edi9999, yes, it is because in the official source from WHATWG you have only recommendations, wich browsers uses for rendering as rules. Each browser can implement this rules and can do this and all other things on own way. **You have no more rules.** What you can do it is to look **attentively** how it is implemented by each browser and could try to implement it on the same way. And from me you have got the good hint (*like next rule*) that on the end you can ignore `<br>` elements. Please, think a while about my words. 

Answer (score 3):

***Please take a look at my more informed, updated answer.***

---

[Here's a W3 doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#edef-P) that states that browsers are expected to ignore empty p elements. The definition of "ignore" is kind of loose, so consider the following snippets:

```html
<p>hello</p>
<p></p>
<p>hello</p>
```

It will render more or less the same as your code:

```html
<p>hello<br /></p>
<p>hello</p>
```

That isn't to say that the elements are completely scrubbed from the page. Applying a style reveals that they've just been shrunk.

```html
<p>hello<br style="margin-bottom: 100px"/></p>
<p>hello up there!</p>
```

Here is some more documentation and a few additional links which ask similar questions.

[W3 doc on Whitespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#whitespace)

[Change Height of Line Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br)

[Empty Paragraph Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848326/empty-paragraph-tags-should-i-allow-in-html-editor-or-not)

Comment: I think you're on to something. You can tell from applying a margin to the <br> that collapsing margins are at work, too. Whether or not *that* is crucial or relevant is something else...

Comment: @BoltClock The big idea of this post was to convey that <br> breaks text into separate lines, and if a line doesn't have text, it is rendered with a height of 0px, similar to how the standard calls for an empty <p> to be rendered with a height of 0px.

Comment: @kalkronline the part of the "empty" `<p>` are rendered with a height of 0px seems quite promising, can you please dig a little bit deeper and update your answer ? (Or if you don't have the permissions to do it, you can answer with an other answer).

Answer (score 3):

The `<br>` element has a single, well-defined purpose — to create a line break in a block of text.

> A line break is defined to be a carriage return (`&#x000D;`), a line feed (`&#x000A;`), or a carriage return/line
> feed pair. All line breaks constitute white space.

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#line-breaks

---

Let's brute force a test, to see which tags render the `<br/>` at the end, and which do not.
https://jsfiddle.net/t7bnokzc/1/

We can see that these tags completely ignore the last `<br/>` as in they do not go to the next line, and show the text right next to them.

```
<button>
<canvas>
<img>
<iframe>
<input>
<ruby>
<meter>
<progress>
<select>
<svg>
<textarea>
<video>
```

Meanwhile these tags ignore the last `<br/>` :

```
<address>
<article>
<aside>
<audio> // Has a default height and width, differs from browser to browser
<blockquote>
<center>
<datalist>
<dd>
<details>
<dir>
<div>
<dl>
<dt>
<fieldset>
<figcaption>
<figure>
<footer>
<form>
<h1>
<header>
<legend>
<li>
<main>
<nav>
<ol>
<optgroup>
<option>
<p>
<pre>
<section>
<summary>
<ul>
```

What do these above have in common? They've got either a `display:block` or a `display:list-item`.

**Conclusion :**

If you put a line break at the end of an element that doesn't render line breaks (list above) or an element that at it's end there's an element that doesn't render line breaks it gets ignored.

Another example :

```html
<address>Hello
  <b>ddg<br></b>
  <b>ddg<br></b>
</address>
```

Knowing that `address` tag is a block element, it behaves exactly as the `p` tag, knowing that the `b` tag behaves like the `a` tag : they render the last line break unless it ends inside a block element.

Comment: With following HTML, `<p>Hello <a href="https://ddg.gg">ddg<br></a><a href="https://ddg.gg">ddg<br></a></p>`, the first br is rendered, so the sentence `If you put it at the end of basically any HTML tag, with no text after, it gets ignored` is probably not completely correct.

Comment: @edi9999 edited my answer, did some brute force digging, tested case by case, and the answer showed up itself.

Answer (score 2):

`br` element behaves like plain blocking element with 0 size, therefore in your cases it just adds 0px to the end of `p` (or `a`). When another text follows any blocking element, it will be placed under (Therefore creating line break). When there is no text, there is no extra space at the end.

This is common behavior for content-editable to place `br` on the end of each line, alongside with wrapping each line into `p` element

As mentioned in comments, implmentation may be different between browsers, but in the end logic is the same, blocking element with no size.

Comment: What is a "blocking element"?

Comment: One, that blocks whole line (like `div`, `p`, etc. , basically anything having `diplay: block` or `display: flex`). Addon: BR is not exactly blocking element, but it behaves so

Comment: @SergeS I would appreciate you explaining a bit more your answer with some examples and cited authorative sources.

Answer (score 2):

Why we use **br tag** - The HTML **br element** produces a line break in text **(carriage-return)**. **carriage-return or return** is a control character or mechanism used to reset a device's position to the **beginning of a line of text**.

**Point to Note:**

If you check the dimensions of **br tag**, it has width = 0 and some height(~18px). But if you use it inside the **p tag** then **br tag** takes the height of **p element** *but the important thing is its own width is 0*.

**Answer to your question**

if we use it as = `<p>Hello<br></p>`
then you will be able to see **br element in developer console** but no extra space, **because we don't have any text after **br tag** and its own width is 0, so overall width becomes zero. Hence it does not take any extra space or line break.**
Example -

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello<br></p>
<p>Hello<br></p>
```

But if we have code like this - `<p>Hello<br>World</p>`
then **br tag** takes the cursor to beginning of the next line and we have text after **br tag** with some width. So, we will be able to see extra space or line break.
Example -

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello<br>World</p>
<p>Hello<br>World</p>
```

And I agree this is not the right place to use **br tag** because p element will automatically add a line break. So, using **br tag** just before end **p tag** makes no sense.

Please check below links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element

Answer (score 2):

From what I have observed is that `<br>` elements cause trailing `inline` elements to be rendered onto the next line. In your case:

```
<p>Hello<br></p>
<p>Hello</p>
```

The `<br>` can't cause trouble to the sibling `p` tag because they are by default `block` elements. If you apply a bit of CSS:

```
p {
    display: inline;
}
```

You will see that your `<br>` tag will render the sibling `<p>` tag to render onto the next line.

I think it just boils down to `display` property of trailing `element(s)`, if they are `inline` aka. in the text flow, those `element(s)` will find themselves under the effect of `<br>` otherwise, if there is any other renderable element(s) of different `display` property, they won't be affected by it.

As @karlkronline said, it might very well be true that the `<br>` elements mark the end of current line. And, if your next "visible" element to be rendered is an `inline` element, it moves to next line and render it. However, if of any other type, since elements are by default rendered on a separate line, there's no point to move again to the next line and render the element. *It might just be enough to see that we will already be on the next line so, ignore and continue rendering.*

**To render an explicit `<br>` b/w `block` elements**, use 2 `<br>`s. They will technically turn out to be just 1 line break. **Why would it work?** It would work because when first `<br>` marks it as next line, the renderer would encounter another `<br>` which is an `inline` element by default so, moving to next line makes sense. But, for the second `<br>` when it marks it as next line, the next element would be `block`, which will already be rendered on a separate line so, ignored.

Concluding, in the expression form:

```
<br> followed by <INLINE ELEMENT> = Next line starting with <INLINE ELEMENT>
<br> followed by <BLOCK ELEMENT> = Ignore since <BLOCK ELEMENT> will render on the next line anyway
```

Answer (score 1):

Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014077/html-specification-for-rendering-new-lines/41685979) which gives an explanation much more elegant than I ever could come up with. I'll try to summarize and apply it to your situation. Let's take another look at your code.

```html
<p>hello<br/></p>
<p>howdy</p>

<hr/>

<p>hello</p>
<p>howdy</p>
```

The code above and below the horizontal rule renders the exact same.

***WHY?***

Well, as user Rei explains, it's because "the BR element is not ignored at all. It marks that the line must be broken at that point. **In other words, it marks the end of the current line of text. It is not about creating new lines."** We know that it isn't ignored because we are able to apply styles to it. As I discovered earlier, making the margin larger than the default reveals that the break is still there.

Consider looking at the other answer for more details. The user who asked the question allegedly is making a similar program, and the answer has plenty of examples and documentation linked. `p` and `div` are both [block level elements,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) so keep that in mind as you read the post.

## TLDR: BR does not automatically make a newline, it just marks the end of the current line of text.

Comment: @Bharata Sorry, but I'm having a hard time understanding what you wrote... My answer here says that the `<br/>` tag signifies the end of a line. Your first example has width because the `p` tag isn't empty, it has the line break in it. Your second example is two lines long because it has two line endings. Your third example is empty because, well, your `p` tags are empty. It would be helpful if you could rephrase your edit so I can understand more clearly what you are trying to point out. I don't think I am misinterpreting what Rei said.

Comment: It was not really clearly written in my answer about the user's *Rei* misinterpretation.  I have changed it. It is not your misinterpretation. Sorry! Please delete your comment above.

Comment: Please read my explanation about user's *Rei* misinterpretation  in my answer in this topic.

Comment: @Bharata Like I said before, the examples you gave are clearly explained above. The reason the second line of the second example has width is because there is a line break character on the second line. It doesn't make sense to have two line endings on one line, so the browser renders two. Also, sorry I can't comment under your answer, I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

The `<br>` elements are always rendered in all browsers, since all browsers are aligned to follow a particular specification amended by the W3C Consortium, but in some instances their effects gets hidden.

You will understand, why it is so, when you get a deeper perspective on how the `<br>` and `<p>` tags work in this particular context of your question. So let us take a deeper look.

**The `<br>` tag** - When applied after a content, it leaves a line break, two `<br>` tags simultaneously can leave a single line of space between visible texts as seen between paragraphs.  **Note:** By virtue of design of `<br>` tags, every subsequent `<br>` tag after two consecutive `<br>` tags will insert a single line of empty space(*Note: A single line of empty space is conventionally known as a **paragraph break***) instead of a line break.

**The `<p>` tag** - It does ensure that, there is an empty line of space on either side of the embedded content(Note: The empty lines of space within the content that precedes or succeeds it, are treated as part of the content itself). It does not take into account of any line breaks ( **Note:** It takes two line breaks to leave an empty line of space(*Paragraph Break*) ie; 2 `<br>` tags & *every subsequent `<br>` tags after 2 consequent `<br>` tags insert a line of empty space instead of a line break.*).

Take a look at the following code snippets.

1.

```html
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
This is a paragraph.
```

In the above code snippet, see that the first line of text is within the `<p>` tag while the second line is not, and it functions as i described above.

2.

```html
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

In the above code snippet, both the texts are embedded within 2 separate `<p>` tags, still there is only a single line of empty space between them. This is because the `<p>` tag will only consider the empty lines of space that are part of the text/content while leaving its own empty line of space.
You'll get more clarity as you examine the code snippets below.

3.

```html
<p>This is a paragraph.<br></p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

In the above code snippet, a single `<br>` tag is embedded within the **first `<p>` tag**, but see that a single `<br>` is not equivalent to an empty line of space( it takes 2 `<br>` tags to be equivalent to an empty line of space). So **an empty line of space is not part of our first text content** so you will not see the effect of `<br>` tag, as a single line break is not equivalent of a line of space & `<p`> tag only takes into account of preceding lines of space before inserting its own single line of space.
By virtue of design, the `<p>` tag will consider the empty lines of space within an element as part of that element, so in case an element has empty lines of space towards its end then the `<p>` tag still leaves its own single line of empty space thus adding an extra blank line to the already existing lines of spaces of the content, Look at the example that follows.

4.

```html
<p>This is a paragraph.<br><br></p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

In the above code snippet, 2 `<br>` tags have been inserted inside the **first `<p>` tag** so it leaves an empty line of space as part of the **first `<p>` tag**. The **second `<p>` tag** will consider this empty line of space as a part of the content within the **first `<p>` tag** and when it insert its own single line of space after the previous content, it seems as if an extra blank line of space have been added to it.

5.

```html
<p>This is a paragraph.<br><br><br></p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

In the above code snippet, you can see 3 `<br>` tags are part of the **first `<p>` tag**, *now scroll up and look at the functioning of `<br`> tags as i described in the begining*, you can see that now 2 lines of empty space are part of the content inside **first `<p>` tag**, hence the spacing between the either `<p>` tags are of 3 lines of empty space(2 empty lines by virtue of 3 `<br>` tags and 1 empty line by virtue of the succeeding `<p>` tag).

Hope this address your doubt, please also do refer this [BR tag has no effect when parent has height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969955/br-tag-has-no-effect-when-parent-has-height), to get a different perspective.